# docker mysql, send sql commands during exec

Tags: docker, docker-exec

i am creating a mysql 5.6 docker using bash script and i would like to change the password.
how can i send sql commands from bash to docker?

build: 
sudo docker build -t mysql-5.6 -f ./.Dockerfile .

run.sh:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    sudo docker run --name=mysql1 -d mysql-5.6
    sudo docker exec -it mysql1 mysql -uroot -p$base_password \
        <<< SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_pass');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind MySQL-port like descriped [here](https://runnable.com/docker/binding-docker-ports). To keep the port 3306 you can just expose it on your host the following way:

```
sudo docker run --name=mysql1 -p 3306:3306 -d mysql-5.6
```

After that you should be able to use `mysql -u USER -p PASSWORD` on your local host. This will then allow you to send commands to your docker-container.